# How to Parse this json object nested in json array

Tags: java, android, json

I am using this code

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");


        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            bookItems bookItem = new bookItems();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject bookChapter = jsonObject.getJSONObject("chapter");
                bookItem.setbook_subtitle(bookChapter.getString("subtitle"));

                JSONObject chapVerses = jsonObject.getJSONObject("verses");
                JSONArray verseReaders = chapVerses.getJSONArray("readers");
                JSONObject readersNum = verseReaders.getJSONObject("number");
                verseReadNum = readersNum;


            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
            mbookItemsList.add(bookItem);

        } 

    }
```

to  parse this json.

```
[
  {
    "chapter": {
      "subtitle": "Something happened in this in this chapter"
    },
    "verses": {
      "about": [
        {
          "In this verse, a lot of things happened yes a lot!"
        }
      ],
      "readers": [
        {
          "read": false,
          "number": "No body has read this verse yet"
        }
      ],

    }
  }, 
  ...]
```

I am getting the "subtitle" correctly but I am having didfficulty getting "number".

From line `JSONObject readersNum = verseReaders.getJSONObject("number");` Android studio is complaining that *getJSONOBJECT (int) in JSONArray cannnot be applied to (java.lang.String)*

Please, how do I properly parse this?

Comment: You know, if you use Gson and define a model class, then you wouldn't need to manually parse the Json yourself

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using Volley, does it support Gson?

Comment: Sure, there is even a custom GsonRequest at the bottom of the [Volley Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verseReaders` is a `JSONArray`, so you need to iterate over (or take the first) `JSONObject` and then get the string from that object.

```
String readersNum = verseReaders.getJSONObject(0).getString("number");
```

Comment: Please can you be kind enough to give your answer in code?

Comment: Thanks, but just a little explanation. You wrote `0` why not 1 or 2 or any other number?

Comment: The 0 means the first JSONObject from the JSONArray

Comment: Yes since I wasn't sure how you were intending to use the readers array I just showed it grabbing the first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nested loops. Just add one more `for` for "readers".